# How can I use JOIN and CASE WHEN statement in this case (sqlite android)

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I have two table)

```
CREATE TABLE `Company` (
    `companyName`   TEXT,
    `status`    TEXT,
    `extra` TEXT,
    `companyId` TEXT,
    `companySecondId`   TEXT
```

```
CREATE TABLE `UserList` (
    `userName`  TEXT,
    `companyId` TEXT
);
```

And I'd like to join UserList and Company with companyId

Data example)

```
companyName     status  extra  companyId  companySecondId
"CompanyA"  "456"   "456"   "A" "A"
"CompanyB"  "789"   "789"   "B" "A"
"CompanyC"  "123"   "123"   "C" "E"
"CompanyD"  "111"   "111"   "D" "D"
```

```
UserName  CompanyId
"UserA" "A"
"UserB" "B"
"UserC" "C"
"UserD" "D"
```

Here is the situation.

1. Company can merge
   CompanyB is merged to A
2. Company can be bankrupt
   CompanyC had been merged to CompanyE but CompanyE was bankrupt.

In this case I join like this

```
select UserList.*, t1.companyName
    from UserList 
    inner join (
        select companyId, 
            (case when exists 
                (select * from Company where a.companySecondId = companyId) 
            then (select companyName from Company where a.companySecondId = companyId) 
            else (select companyName from Company where a.companyId = companyId) 
            end) as companyName 
        from Company a
    ) as t1 on UserList.companyId = t1.companyId
```

If each User's companyId is existed in Company Table with "companySecondId" then show companySecondId's companyName

If each User's companyId is not existed in Company Table with "companySecondId" then show companyId's companyName insteadOf companySecondId

So I can get the result like this

```
userName  companyId  companyName
"UserA" "A" "CompanyA"
"UserB" "B" "CompanyA"
"UserC" "C" "CompanyC"
"UserD" "D" "CompanyD"
```

But I'd like to show with status and extra like this
but case when exist ~ then ~ else only return one column. How can I do that in SQLite??

```
userName  companyId  companyName  status  extra
"UserA"     "A"     "CompanyA"        "456"    "456"
"UserB"     "B"     "CompanyA"        "456"    "456"
"UserC"     "C"     "CompanyC"        "123"    "123"
"UserD"     "D"     "CompanyD"        "111"    "111"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic in the question is a little hard to follow.  However, I think you are just looking for `left join`:

```
select ul.userName,
       coalesce(c2.companyId, c.companyId) as companyId,
       coalesce(c2.status, c.status) as status,
       coalesce(c2.extra, c.extra) as extra
from userlist ul left join
     company c
     on ul.companyId = c.companyId left join
     company c2
     on c2.companyId = c.companySecondId;
```

The second `left join` is there mostly to see if the second company exists in the table.

Comment: Wow Thank you!!! I didn't know "coalesce" at all. Thanks..!! :) You are an angel!!